# nscoder swift cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

I'm trying to implement autocorrection through [SymSpell](https://github.com/Archivus/SymSpell)

I've created the dictionary in the container app and should save it and read it from the keyboard extension

the dictionary contains a `dictionaryItem` object which needs to be serialized to be saved by NSCoder

I tried to add the methods to the object but I got an error "init(coder adecoder nscoder) swift cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder"

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   if let suggestions = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("suggestions") as? [Int] {
      self.suggestions = suggestions
  }
      if let count = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("count") as? Int {
         self.count = count
      }
}
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
     if let count = self.count as? Int {
        aCoder.encodeObject(count, forKey: "count")
     }
    if let suggestions = self.suggestions as? [Int] {
        aCoder.encodeObject(suggestions, forKey: "suggestions")
     }
}
```

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

class SuggestionModel: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var suggestions: [Int]?
    var count : Int?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.suggestions = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("suggestions") as? [Int]
        self.count = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("count") as? Int
        super.init()
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.count, forKey: "count")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.suggestions, forKey: "suggestions")
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```